# Var in my code doesn't works

Tags: javascript, jquery

"Var" in my code doesn't works.
It always shows `'hasclass = 0 and body has class'` but should `hasclass = yes and body has class`

```
setInterval(function() {
if($('.webMessengerMessageGroup').length>0) {
    if(hasclass === 'dooainn') {
        console.log('hasclass = yes and body has class');
    } else {
        var hasclass = 'dooainn';
        console.log('hasclass = 0 and body has class'); 
        $('._38 p').click(function () {
            var message_text = $(this).text();
            console.log(message_text);
        });
    }
} else {
    console.log('body has not class');
} 
},2000);
```

Comment: It looks like `hasclass !== 'dooainn'`. What's the value of `hasClass`?

Comment: @Andy "webMessengerMessageGroup" class creates on page in a few seconds after the page loads and when this class loaded, function doing some function (it 6 line on my page), and as part "var hasclass = 'dooainn';

Comment: @IliaDementiev: Right. And that value only lives until the callback returns. The *next* time the timer fires, you get a whole new variable again. This is, after all, the nature of local variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably heard that `var` is "hoisted," and so you expected your entire

```
var hasclass = 'dooainn';
```

line to move up to the top of the function. But that's not how it works. Only the `var hasclass` part is hoisted. The `hasclass = 'dooainn';` part remains where it is.

So what your code really does is this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var hasclass = undefined;                                // <==
    if($('.webMessengerMessageGroup').length>0) {
        if(hasclass === 'dooainn') {
            console.log('hasclass = yes and body has class');
        } else {
            hasclass = 'dooainn';                            // <==
            console.log('hasclass = 0 and body has class'); 
            $('._38 p').click(function () {
                var message_text = $(this).text();
                console.log(message_text);
            });
        }
    } else {
        console.log('body has not class');
    } 
},2000);
```

So `hasclass` is never going to be `=== "dooainn"`.

More *(on my blog)*: [*Poor, misunderstood `var`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html)

You might have meant to declare it *outside* the callback so that the value persists between calls:

```
var hasclass;                                               // <==
setInterval(function() {
    if($('.webMessengerMessageGroup').length>0) {
        if(hasclass === 'dooainn') {
            console.log('hasclass = yes and body has class');
        } else {
            hasclass = 'dooainn';                            // <==
            console.log('hasclass = 0 and body has class'); 
            $('._38 p').click(function () {
                var message_text = $(this).text();
                console.log(message_text);
            });
        }
    } else {
        console.log('body has not class');
    } 
},2000);
```

Now, on the second call and afterward, it's possible that it may have that value, since you may have assigned it on a previous iteration.

Answer (score 2):

The var hasclass is not defined in scope of the if. If you move the var outside of the function like below it should work.

```
var hasclass = '';
setInterval(function() {
if($('.webMessengerMessageGroup').length>0) {
    if(hasclass === 'dooainn') {
        console.log('hasclass = yes and body has class');
    } else {
        hasclass = 'dooainn';
        console.log('hasclass = 0 and body has class'); 
        $('._38 p').click(function () {
            var message_text = $(this).text();
            console.log(message_text);
        });
    }
} else {
    console.log('body has not class');
} 
},2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct, your issue is that the **var** declaration is scoped to only be inside the "else" statement.  However, I thought I'd offer an alternative for you so that your setInterval doesn't continue to run for ever and ever. This code will only re-execute your webMessengerMessageGroup check after waiting 2 seconds if the last check failed.

```
var addClickFunc = function(){    
    if($('.webMessengerMessageGroup').length>0) {
        $('._38 p').click(function () {
            var message_text = $(this).text();
            console.log(message_text);
        });
    } else {
        setTimeout(addClickFunc,2000);
    }    
};

setTimeout(addClickFunc,2000);
```

Another alternative to get away from having to check for the presence of a selector at all is to use a delegate, which can be set up at any time.

```
$(document).on('click', '._38 p',function () {
    var message_text = $(this).text();
    console.log(message_text);
});
```